# Delete duplicate records in group - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables that I need to update each week. I will have duplicates of a unique identifier in the file which I need to delete the duplicates based on the Max value of another field, however, there may be duplicates of the max field.

```
TrackID  |  GrossOpens    (Amoung other fields...)  
1     |     2  
1     |     1  
2     |     5  
2     |     10  
2     |     10  
3     |     3
```

I have been able to get my data to get the following results:

```
TrackID  |  GrossOpens  
1    |      2  
2    |      10  
2    |      10  
3    |      3
```

I need the duplicates that have matching "GrossOpens" to be removed in each group. I used the following code to get the adove results:

```
DELETE *  
FROM NL_2015 AS NL  
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM NL_2015 DL WHERE DL.TrackID = NL.TrackID AND   (DL.GrossOpens > NL.GrossOpens OR (DL.GrossOpens = NL.GrossOpens AND DL.TrackID   > NL.TrackID)));
```

Comment: I thought adding a Ranking or Row_Number to the "GrossOpens" might work but wasnt sure how to accomplish this properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a row number using this query and all duplicates will have a row number superior to 1.

```
WITH dupes
AS (
  SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TrackID ORDER BY grossopens DESC) row
  FROM NL_2015)
DELETE FROM dupes
WHERE  row > 1
```

---

Edit for the query without `WITH`:

```
DELETE FROM  (
  SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TrackID ORDER BY grossopens DESC) row
  FROM NL_2015
)
WHERE 
row > 1
```

Comment: Actually you'd want to `order by grossopens desc` and then this would work.

Comment: Thanks, @JustinLessard! My only problem is I am using Access to accomplish this which does not support a WITH statement. How else could i re-write as a SELECT, UPDATE, or DELETE?